# Rails: second-level associations/undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

I have these methods:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fabrics
end

class Fabric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  has_many :inventories
end

class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fabric
end
```

Controller:

```
class InventoryController < ApplicationController

def index
  @inventory = Inventory.all
end
```

And view:

```
<% @inventory.each do |f| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.fabric.item %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `item' for nil:NilClass):
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this error? Is it because of scopes? I've read Active Record Associations Guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference). Under '4.1.3.2 includes' there is an example similar to my model associations which says this should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that some of the inventories does not have related fabric, etc `inventory.fabric == nil`. You need to manage this case in the view code:

```
<% @inventory.each do |f| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.fabric ? f.fabric.item : "Without item" %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I ran Inventory.where(fabric_id: nil) in rails console and found one record with fabric_id == nil! I destroyed that record and everything works now! Thank you Ilya!